# Fluent NHibernate mapping - converting n-m to 1-n relation

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have created three entities:

```
public class Company : EntityBase
{
   some properties
   public virtual IList<UserCompanyAttachment> AttachedUsers {get; set;}

   public virtual void AttachUser(User userToAttach)
   {
       var userCompanyAttachment = new UserCompanyAttachment()
       {
           AttachedCompany = this,
           AttachedUser = userToAttach
       }
       AttachedUsers.Add(userCompanyAttachment);
   }
}

public class User : EntityBase
{
   some properties
   public virtual IList<UserCompanyAttachment> AttachedCompanies {get; set;}

   public virtual void AttachCompany(Company companyToAttach)
   {
       var userCompanyAttachment = new UserCompanyAttachment()
       {
           AttachedCompany = companyToAttach,
           AttachedUser = this
       }
       AttachedCompanies.Add(userCompanyAttachment);
   }
}

public class UserCompanyAttachment : EntityBase
{
    public virtual User AttachedUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Company AttachedCompany { get; set; }
     .. some properties ..
}
```

And I've created relationships with fluent - Company and Users mappings got:

```
HasMany(x => x.AttachedCompanies/Users).Inverse.Cascade.All();
```

UserCompanyAttachemnt mapping is:

```
References(x => x.AttachedUser);
References(x => x.AttachedCompany);
```

The reason why I didn't create normal, many-to-many relation is because I need to store informations about attachments. (there is no redundacy as physically third table will exists in database, in both cases) However when I try for instance attach User with `companyObject.AttachUser(newUser)` change is only visible on `company.AttachedUsers` - but not in `newUser.AttachedCompanies`. Is there any way to push changes with some mapping? Why does it fail?

EDIT: added unit test which fails

```
    [Test]
    public void CanCorrectlyMapUserCompanyAttachmentWhenAddedByUser()
    {
        var testUser = new User() { PasswordHash = "pp", PasswordSalt = "qq", Username = "user" };
        var testCompany = new Company()
        {
            Address = new Address() { City = "q" },
            AgentName = "tt",
            Comments = "z",
            CompanyName = "g",
            MailAddress = "@@",
            NIP = 231123
        };

        DbSession.Save(testUser);
        DbSession.Save(testCompany);
        testUser.AttachCompany(testCompany);
        DbSession.Flush();

        var addedAttachment = DbSession.Get<UserCompanyAttachment>(1);

        User addedUser = DbSession.Get<User>(1);
        Company addedCompany = DbSession.Get<Company>(1);

        Assert.AreEqual(addedAttachment .AttachedUser.Id, 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(addedAttachment .AttachedCompany.Id, 1);
        Assert.IsTrue(addedUser.AttachedCompanies.Contains(addedAttachment));
        Assert.IsTrue(addedCompany.AttachedUsers.Contains(addedAttachment)); // here it fails
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is:

- We did **not** in **C#** assign pairing instance `UserCompanyAttachment` into `AttachedUsers` collection *(of the `Company` instance `testCompany`)*
- We did **not** let the NHibernate to reload all three - just created instances - from DB. All objects where still returned from the session - its first level cache.

So, what we can do is:

1) Also assign the pairing object into the company's collection `AttachedUsers`. But I would not complicate that so much. Because our operations should always be either Read or Write. And each of them should have their own separated/unique ISession. *(i.e. not sharing first level cache)*

2) The preferred way is to leave it on NHibernate. That awesome tool will populate all the collections as we would expect. It just has to be allowed to reload all the stuff from DB. How? Just by one line of code:

```
// creation of all the stuff in the unit test 
...
...
DbSession.Flush();

// new line - essential setting - clearing the first level cache
DbSession.Clear();

// the test continues as it was... passing all assertion
...
```

that simple statement: **`DbSession.Clear();`** is a key to success. Why? Because NHibernate now has a full access to proper instantiation based on DB data... not on the "weakly set relations" in our C#.

And that would be the preferred way: *Split Write and Read == let NHibernate to populate our objects, it will be done properly...*